# should I use a new apple bundle id or use the same bundle id with ios app when publish a macos app

Tags: ios, macos

I am write a flutter app, now I want to package the flutter app as a macos dmg package to install and run in macOS, I already have a ios certificate, should I apply a new bundle id and certificate to publish the macos app or reuse the ios certificate and bundle id? I did not found any guide about this problem from apple.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should use different bundle id for every application you are going to created with apple. No matter you are developing iOS, macOS, watchOS application. Every application should have different bundle id for uniqueness.

The bundleIds resource represents the app's unique identifier that you can register, modify, and delete. You need a bundle ID before you can assign capabilities with the Bundle ID Capabilities resource or create a provisioning profile with the Profiles resource.

Comment: I am use the same source code repo, my flutter code only have one repo for different platform like ios android linux windows, in mac and ios we should use different bundle id? It is a little hard to understand different bundle id for one app. @Rahul Phate

Comment: In short apple maintain unique identifier of every application.